# Detect iOS Form Sheet dismissal of Google Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I've added the Google Sign In feature to my iOS app and set up the appropriate listeners to detect if sign in was started or canceled but I am unable to detect if the google sign in page sheet is dismissed by touching the space outside of the form sheet.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin

In iOS 13+ this would be handled by listening to the UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate. If a user drags the page sheet down or clicks outside, it would call:

```
func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController)
```

It appears that Google has done half of the work because they have restricted the ability to drag to dismiss the view controller. However the click to dismiss on iPad still is unrestricted.

Is there anyway to attach this delegate to the GIDSignIn object? Is there another function that handles the dismissal of Google Sign In in this way?